# datetime format in python for finding column in dataframe

Tags: python, csv, datetime, dataframe, automation

How should I change the date format from 01/13 to 1/13 where the both should be in date format in python?
My dataframe looks like this:
[image]

whereas the intended part of my code looks like this, where I want find a particular cell by its row index and column index, where I got the row index part but the column index is not coming and showing this error:

```
formated_day=(date.today() - timedelta(i)).strftime("%m/%d")
row_number=dataframe_wsheet.loc[dataframe_wsheet[""]==name].index.values
print(row_number)

[5]

dataframe_wsheet.loc[:,formated_day]
```

And it is showing this error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [01/13] is not in the [columns]'
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? `How should I change the date format from 01/13 to 1/13`

Comment: Okay, so the thing is I want to update the cell values datewise  so, I need to have the date in a variable and thats why I used the formated_day variable. dataframe_wsheet is the dataframe that is in the picture. So, I got the row number. but for the column number I need to identify the exact bolumn by the columns labbel which is the date. The formated_day is coming in the format of '01/13' while in the sheet the date is in the format of '1/13', maybe that's why it is unable to find the exact column.